# m2eclipse project - missing 'update dependencies'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I checked out a maven project and imported to my Eclipse (Indigo) with maven integration via the m2eclipse plugin.  I configured the project as a maven project.  When I r click on my project and click Run As... I'm able to see all the maven configurations (maven build, maven clean, maven install etc.)  The project icon has an m indicating that it's a maven project.  When I r click an go to Maven I'm able to see

Add Dependency
Add Plugin
New Maven
Download Javadoc
Download Sources
Update Project
Disable Workspace Resolution
Disable Maven Nature

-I was told that I'd be able to see 'Update Dependencies' under the Maven menu but it seems to be missing.  Is this to be expected given my Eclipse version or something?  Or do I have to configure the project in some way to get 'Update Dependencies' to show up under the Maven menu?

Comment: Are you really using m2eclipse or m2e and in which version? Eclipse Indigo SR2 ?

Comment: I'm using m2e.  Is there a difference?  I'm using Eclipse Indigo EE SR2.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to see the option "Convert to Maven Project" under the "Configure" menu?

Comment: Yes, I was.  After I clicked 'Convert to Maven project' under Configure menu, that menu item went away, but now I can see that the project has been converted for maven because the Maven menu item appears, maven options appear under 'run as', and there is a red M icon on my project.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on m2e in Eclipse Helios, I haven't tried it in later Eclipse versions yet.

On the latest m2e version I installed today, I've found I need to go to Maven / Update Project... in the context menu, then select the options you want.  (The Update Dependencies option seems to be fixed in the "on" position on mine.)

It may be that the current version can still be configured to show the menus as they used to be; I don't know.  I say this because my old version was of a later date than the original post here, but still had the Update Deps and Update Project Conf options in the Maven menu.